# Mongo query getting totals

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

If I had a schema that looked something like this:

```
    var person = new Schema({
         active: {type: Boolean},
         otherSetting: {type: Boolean} 
    });
```

Would it be possible with just **one** query to get the entire total count of all people, total people active, total people inactive, as well as the total count for people with otherSetting set to true and other Setting set to false? Would otherSetting and active have to be broken into two queries?

I've been playing around with the aggregate framework on this problem and although this seems like a simple problem, I can't seem to do it with just one query.

Is it even possible? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) has logical operators such as [**`$cond`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) that work well with your boolean conition here:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": null,
        "active": { "$sum": { "$cond": [ "$active", 1, 0 ] } },
        "inActive": { "$sum": { "$cond": [ "$active", 0, 1 ] } },
        "total": { "$sum": 1 }
    }}
])
```

The `$cond` operator is a "ternary" operator ( if/then/else ) that allows the evaluation of a logical condition to return the `true` ( then ) or `false` ( else ) values.

The "boolean" is evaluated as `true/false` in the first argument to `$cond` which passes the appropriate value to [`$sum`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) in order to get the conditional totals.

Everything works within a single [`$group`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) pipeline stage with a grouping key `_id` of `null` since you want to add up the whole collection. If grouping on the value of another field then replace that `null` with the field you want.

Comment: I know we're supposed to avoid comments like "+1" and "thanks", but this was an amazing answer and very helpful, so thank you!